# Rename and move files from one directory to another directory

Tags: mv, for

Need your help on a command that run on a path1 to rename and move files from path2 to path3

Assume

```
path1 = /data/run/
path2 = /data/output/
path3 = /data/archive/
```

path 2 contains few files like 'one.txt', 'two.txt' etc...

I want to run a command in path1 which can rename the files 'one.txt' to 'archive_one.txt' and move them to path3

I tried the below command from '/data/run' , but it is taking the whole path as file name and throwing error.

```
$for FILENAME in /data/output/*.txt; do mv $FILENAME /data/archive/archive_$FILENAME; done
```

How can I do that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want to do is

```
for FILENAME in /data/output/*.txt; 
do 
   mv "$FILENAME" "/data/archive/archive_$(basename  "$FILENAME")" ; 
done
```

this can be one lined of course.

where

- `basename "$FILENAME"` extract last part of filename
- `basename "$FILENAME" .txt` would do the ame, striping `.txt` part.

and when posting here thou shall quote filename always.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question.  I got a small problem, sometime the file names do not have any extension and that path contains some sub directories too.  In case if I put *.* then the entire files and sub-directories are moved.  Is there a way to restrict to move only the files and not directories?